# MBProgressHUD blocking user interaction

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, nsthread, mbprogresshud

My application has a `MBProgressHUD` on the screen while the `CLLocationManager` is getting the user current location at a separate thread in the background. Sometimes the location process start to take so long and obviously I would like to let the user decide to leave or not the screen. The problem is that the User Interface seems to be blocked by the `MBProgressHUD` so the user can't press the back button.

Is there any implementation design to solve this problem?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In order to achieve a non-modal behavior, simply disable the user interaction on the `MBProgressHUD` so that the touches will fall through it.

**Objective-C**

```
theHUD.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
theHUD.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: does that mean views behind it will receive events? how to disable like buttons behind hud?

Comment: Just disable them until the the data the HUD is loading has been retrieved?

Comment: By setting isUserInteractionEnabled to false, you are telling the control to pass touch event to parent view.